# Home/Landing screen design for a website in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, web-applications, dynamic-data

I have an web based application. The content for the Home page has been currently mentioned in the HTML code for the Home page using ,  and  tags. To change the content anytime in future, it needs to be changed in the HTML code. :(

Is there a way that we can pick up the content from some external place and get it reflected through the website. This ways, any change if required can be made at the external location without referring to the application's code.

Please advise if there is any solution for it.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you thinking about linking in a file? Or you could store it in a database perhaps.

Comment: server side include, perhaps? That'd be a simple option.

Answer (score 0):

You can

1. [Use a database](http://www.asp.net/learn/data-access/)
2. [Include external files using Server Side Includes](http://www.christopherjason.com/asp-net/using-includes-asp-net/)
3. [Read external files and write their contents](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306575) and [an alternative method](http://aspalliance.com/153)

Comment: What's the best possible way of doing it? How can we link it through the file? and then when the website is hosted on IIS, how and where we need to place the file? Can you please elaborate on it a bit. 

The HTML code is like:
<table width="75%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" class="container" align="center">
           <tr><td> TEXT1</td></tr>
           <tr><td> TEXT2</td></tr>
</table>
Currently TEXT1 to TEXT4 are hardcoded. We want that its refrred through some way so that the content can be changed at any time withou referring to the HTML code here.

Any suggestions?  

Thanks

Comment: the above are links that point to explanations and working examples.. here is a simple one .. replace the `TEXT1` with `<!--#include file="SomeFilename.ext"-->`. the `SomeFilename.ext` file should have the contents...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for a Content Management System (CMS), which will allow your content editors access to modify only specific blocks of a page that you specify.

There are a ton out there to do what you want, so you don't have to start from scratch. Just Google 'CMS'.

Although I haven't used it myself, [DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com) is a popular one these days and has a free version.

Comment: I already have complet website in place and is also hosted on IIS. uing CMS might require changes to alredy confgured and functional website. Also i see that some licenses etc might be required. 

Is there any direct way to read from some file etc? Please advise

Thanks,

Comment: @swati, again: Server Side Include